# Xamarin MvvmCross Fluent Binding on UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am making a Windows UWP app and I'm trying to do Fluent Binding on the View, MvxWindowsPage. When I declare the MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();
```

it gives a build time error of:

> The type 'FirstView' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTarget' in the generic type or method There is no implicit reference conversion from 'FirstView' to 'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner'.

My WindowsPage declaration is as follows:

```
using MvvmCross.Uwp.Views;
using MyApp.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
public sealed partial class FirstView : MvxWindowsPage<FirstViewModel>
{
    public FirstView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //This line below gives me the build time error
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();

        set.Bind(myButton)
            .To(viewmodel => viewmodel.DoStuffSelected);
    }
}
```

How do I do Fluent Binding in a UWP App? Or is the support for a UWP app only for Forms bindings?

Comment: Why don't you just bind using XAML?

Comment: XAML is fine if that's more the industry standard. When I've written XAML in the past it felt like the equivalent pages were less responsive in timing. It looks like the new XAML-C is compiled at Build Time so run time parsing isn't the issue it used to be with performance and notification of errors. I have always enjoyed code because I can abstract it into reusable and testable "component's."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by looking at how they implemented this fix in WPF. Not sure if this is 100% correct, but it worked for me implementing MvxInteraction in a MvxWindowsPage view (using MvvmCross v6.2.3):

```
using ExampleApp.Uwp.Interactions;
using ExampleApp.Uwp.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Base;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Uap.Presenters.Attributes;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace ExampleApp.Uwp.Views
{
    public sealed partial class LibrariesView : IMvxBindingContextOwner
    {
        private IMvxInteraction<AppNotificationInteraction> _appNotificationInteraction;
        private IMvxBindingContext _bindingContext;

        public LibrariesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IMvxInteraction<AppNotificationInteraction> AppNotificationInteraction
        {
            get => _appNotificationInteraction;
            set
            {
                if (_appNotificationInteraction != null)
                {
                    _appNotificationInteraction.Requested -= AppNotificationInteractionOnRequested;
                }

                _appNotificationInteraction = value;
                _appNotificationInteraction.Requested += AppNotificationInteractionOnRequested;
            }
        }

        public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext
        {
            get => _bindingContext ?? (_bindingContext = new MvxBindingContext());
            set => _bindingContext = value;
        }

        public new LibrariesViewModel ViewModel => base.ViewModel as LibrariesViewModel;

        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {
            base.OnViewModelSet();

            BindingContext.DataContext = ViewModel;

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LibrariesView, LibrariesViewModel>();
            set.Bind(this).For(view => view.AppNotificationInteraction).To(viewModel => viewModel.AppNotificationInteraction).OneWay();
            set.Apply();
        }

        private void AppNotificationInteractionOnRequested(object sender, MvxValueEventArgs<AppNotificationInteraction> e)
        {
            AppNotification.Show(e.Value.Content);
        }
    }
}
```